# Prolog Integration with Python

Tags: python-3.x, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I would like to use Prolog in a project for university built on Python 3.5. Is there a way to do this? I've come across PySWIP, but it seems to only work for python 2.x. Is there a port available or is Prolog just on its way out when it comes to Python?

Comment: [This pyswip3 fork](https://github.com/f0ma/pyswip3) works well, have no active development.

Comment: It's not working at all for me... Is there some trick to getting that to work?

Comment: What does not work? Can you start the examples/tests of `pyswip3`? What errors do you have?

Comment: I'm getting "AttributeError: function 'PL_initialise' not found" in core.py at  _PL_initialise = _lib.PL_initialise... I can't import Prolog

Comment: `pyswip3` can't find prolog shared library (swipl.dll/libswipl.dll or libswipl.so/swipl.so/pl.so). `pyswip3` uses multiple methods to find where prolog library placed. If you add path to `swipl` to PATH variable method based on call `swipl -dump-runtime-variables` should works.

Comment: But following a debug trace shows it finding the DLLs.... I even tried hardcoding the path to the DLLs in the core.py... is it possible that it doesn't work for SWI-Prolog 7.2?

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#Prolog

Comment: @bendl I've used it with 7.2.2 under Ubuntu 16.10 and under WinXP. Maybe problem with 32/64-bit compatability between python and prolog?